# PHP IF construct when dealing with a part that is an exception

Tags: php, if-statement

I'm having some trouble getting my code to work. And I lost my overview. Who can give me some insight?

I'm looking for how to build an `IF` construct.

If I would describe the IF construct in words:

```
MismatchBundle = true  unless  (adminPass = true & user = admin)
```

I wrote the following code, but this didn't seem to work:

```
if (($MismatchBundle == true)  &&  ($adminPass != true && $thisUser['rankid'] != 1)
```

Anyone who knows how to get the 'unless' part in the code?

What about this?

```
 if (($MismatchBundle == true)  &&  !($adminPass == true && $thisUser['rankid'] == 1)
```

Is this allowed with the ! before a () section?

Comment: Yes, a `!` flips the boolean value of the expression in the parenthesis.

Comment: From your other comments, it sounds like you want `if (($MismatchBundle == true)  || ($adminPass == true && $thisUser['rankid'] == 1)`

Comment: @austin nope, this would give another outcome then I want.
With your example it would always be true for an admin, which is exactly the opposite of what I need. What I need is it to NOT be true for an admin. (described in text as unless)

Comment: Thank you to the guy who gave a -1 to my question and not even bothering to leave a reply. It would be much more helpful if you would write what it is that I'm doing wrong.

Comment: @Paul ok, then just do `if (($MismatchBundle == true) || !($adminPass == true && $thisUser['rankid'] == 1)`.  Same as your last example, but use `||` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (($MismatchBundle == true)  &&  !($adminPass == true && $thisUser['rankid'] == 1)
```

Using ! on the entire section within ( ) worked as intended.